# Is there a way to apply textures to a bitmap or true-type font?

Tags: fonts, libgdx, textures

I am using Libgdx and I am trying to get the font that appears for my score to look a certain way. I downloaded a custom font texture pack which includes PNGs of the completed textures, PNG sprite sheets of the different layers used, and the base .ttf file that the textures were based on.

[Here is a link to the images which show the intended result](https://www.gamedeveloperstudio.com/graphics/viewgraphic.php?item=1q4u4q2g671a3n690a)

I have looked through the documentation on bitmap and true-type fonts but haven't been able to come up with the usages I need.

Comment: This app is made with LibGDX and intended to produce fonts specifically for LibGDX. I think it has similar functionality to ShoeBox as far as converting images into a BitmapFont. But I haven't tried it myself to know for sure. https://ray3k.wordpress.com/software/skin-composer-for-libgdx/

Comment: can you re post this as an answer so that I can set this as the accepted answer, this fixed my issue perfectly

Comment: It’s against the rules to post an answer that just recommends a resource.

Comment: Noted. Well in any case, hats off to you my friend. That worked better than I expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "ShoeBox" font editor and I'm really satisfied with it. Check out this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxPf1M7YORU

To be precise - it can create bitmap font. Even if you succeed in applying texture to true-type font you can never get results good as this (effects & stuff).

Comment: I tried using shoebox but whenever i export the fnt file, the .png files that is needed is blank. The thumbnail image is just black and when i click on it there isnt anything in the file. I put the files into android studio and I get an error loading the file, that says no glyphs found